# template field column of gridview is being created on each click

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

this is aspx code in which I put a grid view in ajax panel.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="head_code" >
        </asp:GridView>

        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Following is code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace gridview_button
{

public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page, ITemplate
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
hitechLatestEntities database = new hitechLatestEntities();
GridView1.DataSource = database.HEADs;

TemplateField tfObject = new TemplateField();
tfObject.HeaderText = "Sub-Head";

tfObject.ItemTemplate = new WebForm2(ListItemType.Item); 

GridView1.Columns.Add(tfObject);
GridView1.DataBind();

}

/////////////////////////////// For template field //////////////////////////////////

public WebForm2()
{ 
}

public WebForm2(ListItemType Item)
{
myListItemType = Item;
}

private ListItemType myListItemType;

public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
{

if (myListItemType == ListItemType.Item)
{
Button btn = new Button();
container.Controls.Add(btn);
}
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
}
```

I have created template field dynamically and Above code is working fine but only problem is that every time when i click on button in template field, a new blank template field column appears with same header text. Even ajax is not working for me.

Comment: You need to put the adding of the field in `Page_Load` in to an `if(!IsPostback)` block. It is re-added on each postback if you don't do this.

Comment: even then it is not working fine. then no other column appears but all button suddenly disappears from template field

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
hitechLatestEntities database = new hitechLatestEntities();
GridView1.DataSource = database.HEADs;

TemplateField tfObject = new TemplateField();
tfObject.HeaderText = "Sub-Head";

tfObject.ItemTemplate = new WebForm2(ListItemType.Item); 

GridView1.Columns.Add(tfObject);
GridView1.DataBind();
}

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="head_code" >
        </asp:GridView>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="GridView1" />
        </Triggers> 
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
```

You can get help from these links
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/513399/UpdateplusPanelplusdataplusisplusnotplusrefreshing

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Comment: even then it is not working fine. then no other column appears but all buttons suddenly disappears from template field